# Set print orientation to landscape with a c# Winforms WebBrowser Control

Tags: c#, winforms, printing

I need to programmatically change the print orientation for one of my webbrowser controls in a winforms app. From what I'm reading in other posts... it looks like the only way to do it is via a programmatic registry edit, print, then change the registry back.

Is this the only solution? If so, can anyone help with the correct way to do this in code?

Answer (score 2):

I figured... Here's how its done in WPF:

```
var dialog = new PrintDialog(); 

if (dialog.ShowDialog() == true) 
{
     System.Printing.PrintTicket pt = dialog.PrintTicket;
     pt.PageOrientation = System.Printing.PageOrientation.Landscape;

     dialog.PrintTicket = pt;

     // Print the element. 
     dialog.PrintVisual(ReportContentPresenter, "Report"); 
}
```

Weird part here is that though, you'll not find PrintTicket in System.Printing even after adding reference to this DLL. You'll also have to add a reference of ReachFramework to get PrintTicket in the intelisense.. Microsoft never stops creating mysteries out of simple things..!! Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:
printDialog.Document.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;